# How to convert this Raw query into Laravel Eloquent way?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is my raw query.

> DB::raw("SELECT * FROM tble WHERE status=1  and now() BETWEEN
>   start_time and end_time ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")

How to convert this into Laravel Eloquent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a model for the table `app/Table.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Table extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tble';
}
```

Logic

```
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

$result = \App\Table::where('status', 1)
    ->where('start_time', '<=', $now)
    ->where('end_time', '>=', $now)
    ->orderBy('id')
    ->first();
```

Comment: Thank you for detail answer,quite useful

Comment: This query prints this.
select * from `questions` where `status` = 1 and `start_time` >= '2017-05-22 10:03:48' and `end_time` <= '2017-05-22 10:03:48' order by `id` asc,it return null,even if value exits between this range

Comment: @KhiradBanu i meant check my updated answer. The eloquent query had the wrong date comparison before. Change your code to use the new one from my answer. The correct check is `start_time <= '2017-05-22 10:03:48' and end_time >= '2017-05-22 10:03:48' ` which is wrong in your query.

Comment: Thank you @Sandeesh

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table('tble')::where('status',1)
                 ->where('start_time', '<=', Carbon::now())
                 ->where('end_time', '>=', Carbon::now())
                 ->orderBy('id')
                 ->first();
```

You can use simple date handling package [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) to achieve this.

Comment: Use where('status', '=', 1) instead of where('status', 1). -> Laravel 5.4 need it.

Comment: You might also consider defining an [Eloquent Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#defining-models). For example here, your model for the table 'tble' would be 'Tble' you could then replace DB::table('tble'):: for Tble::

Comment: @PatrykWoziński You can still pass 2 params to a where clause in Laravel 5.4 and it will assume the operator is `=`.

Comment: @ThunderBird, you might want to consider using `<=` and `>=` because *BETWEEN* is inclusive of the range. One issue that the OP might have to be aware of is the issues with time zone - especially if the time used in the app is consistent.

Comment: @thunderbird you should change the date check since the author wants to check if the current time is between the fields. Secondly you should add `first()` or `take(1)->get()` since the author wants to limit the result by 1 row

Comment: This query prints this.
select * from `questions` where `status` = 1 and `start_time` >= '2017-05-22 10:03:48' and `end_time` <= '2017-05-22 10:03:48' order by `id` asc,it return null,even if value exits between this range

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 DB::table('tble')::where('status',1)
                      ->whereBetween(Carbon::now(), ['start_time', 'end_time'])
                      ->orderBy('id')
                      ->first();
```

Comment: This will print.
elect * from `questions` where `status` = 1 and `2017-05-22 10:08:16` between start_time and end_time order by `id` asc limit 1,which is wrong.